# Same function in Python and C, different results

Tags: python, c

I had the following function written in Python as part of a larger simulation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
counter = 1
while (counter < 10000):
    oldpa = .5
    t = 1
    while (t < counter):
        newpa = ((oldpa * t) + 1) / (t + 1)
        t = t + 1
        oldpa = newpa
    counter = counter + 1
    print str(counter) + "\t" + str(oldpa)
```

Then, I started rewriting the simulation in C so that it would run faster (and also to give myself an excuse to spend time learning C). Here's my C version of the above function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int counter, t;
  float oldpa, newpa;
  counter = 1;
  while ( counter < 10000 )
    {
      oldpa = .5;
      t = 1;
      while ( t < counter )
        {
          newpa = ((oldpa * t) + 1) / (t + 1);
          t = t + 1;
          oldpa = newpa;
        }
      counter = counter + 1;
      printf("%d\t%f\n", counter, oldpa);
   }
}
```

Now, here is the funny thing. When I run the Python function, the result converges to 0.999950, but when I run the C function, it converges to 0.999883. This difference is actually negligible for the purposes of my simulation, but I still want to know why I get different results

Comment: The c program doesn't work for me at all, the `counter + counter + 1;` line is wrong.

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: The fixed version converges to `0.999950` too. What platform, compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Have you tried double precision as opposed to floats?

Comment: I got .999950 when running the C version with GCC 4.7 on Fedora 17 64bit

Comment: I got `0.999883` just once when experimenting with compilation flags and couldn't get it again even with the same flags.

Comment: I got .999950 when running the C version with GCC 4.7.2 on Mac OS 10.8.2.

Comment: fixed version on Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc version 4.6.3 gives 0.999950

Comment: As gpv0001 suggested, the C function converges to 0.999950 when using either double or long double instead of float for oldpa and newpa. Case closed.

For reference, I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 11.04 (I'm at home, so I'm using my semi-old laptop) and I compiled with gcc 4.5.2 only with the -o flag.

Comment: Found my mistake. Of course with doubles it always works properly, and with floats it works wrong only when SSE2 floating point math is not used.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point values in Python are almost always IEEE-754 [double precision](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), corresponding to a C or C++ `double`. If you want a lot more precision, check out the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).